# "require external module babel-register" takes long time to execute

Tags: node.js, gulp, babeljs

I am new to gulp, whenever I run `gulp SOME_TASK` it says "require external module babel-register". This takes a solid 20 seconds or so. The actual task takes milliseconds to complete.

What is happening here? How do I fix it? What is this babel-register?

I tried `npm install babel-register`. It did not fix the problem.

Comment: If you're on npm 2, that is your problem and you should run dedupe or update to npm 3.

Comment: I updated to npm3 and downloaded babel-register using npm3. The problem persists.

Comment: Did you uninstall the node_modules you already had before re-installing `babel-register`? Best to totally delete `node_modules` and install from scratch.

Comment: No joy, did not work.I dont recall using it anywhere. What is this babel-register? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Babel register is necessary to transpile ES2015 to ES5 on the fly, without a task. If you have a gulpfile.babel.js and a .babelrc, that's what's using it. Take a look at the docs for .babelrc and tutorials for "gulpfile with ES6/2015", you'll find information there.

Answer (score 1):

```js
{
  ...,
  "retainLines": true
}
```

Adding this to my .babelrc made everything a lot faster!

Comment: But this would also mean that it wont minify your code. AFAIK. Regardless, interesting discovery.

Comment: Yeah, for production code you might wanna remove this again.
But in debug mode it is great.